# Does Karma accumulate over resets?

Tags: kittens-game

When I reset the game, do I only have the karma that results from the kitten count from that stage or does karma accumulate?

Comment: The first attribute of karma is to accumulate through resets. Karma is the first ressource one can get to accumulate through resets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the source code](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/src/2309b6eb80cbea540f0ec5c2deca7fdebfdf151f/game.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#game.js-1799) we can see that karma accumulates over resets. Meaning, you retain your original karma and gain additional karma on top.